# What is this image for in jQuery UI?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

```
.ui-widget-content
{border:1px solid #aaa;background:#fff 
url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
```

I found in jQuery UI css there is a non-sense pure white picture. Why do they use a picture rather than just pure color as the background?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this picture contains a sprite with buttons used by Jquery UI:
 [image: Sprite]

Your version of jQuery UI is probobly corrupted, if that file is blank white.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that's the case... usually the icon sprite is called ui-icons_xxx (e.g. ui-icons_222222_256x240.png).


The ui-bg_flat_xxx files (e.g. ui-bg_flat_10_000000_40x100.png) are indeed solid colours... not sure what benefit over a solid background colour though.

Comment: So mabe the specific theme you downloaded just dose not use that file?